# knitr chunk to parametrize a chapter master file

Tags: r, latex, knitr

I'm writing a book using a book.Rnw master file to compile the whole thing and a chapter.Rnw file to compile just a single chapter. I have to do this because it takes too long to compile the whole book when I'm working on one chapter, and knitr doesn't support the `\includeonly{}` facility of LaTeX because it writes all child documents to a single file, rather than
separate files than can be `\include{}`ed.

To keep the page and chapter/section numbers straight in the chapter, I use the following LaTeX in chapter.Rnw,
but comment out those lines for other chapters, unless it is the last.

```
\documentclass[11pt]{book}
...

% Ch 1
\setcounter{chapter}{0} % one less than chapter number
\setcounter{page}{0}    % one less than book page number

% Ch 2
\setcounter{chapter}{1} % one less than chapter number
\setcounter{page}{18}   % one less than book page number
...    

% Ch 7
\setcounter{chapter}{6} % one less than chapter number
\setcounter{page}{236}  % one less than book page number
```

followed by a child chunk for the current chapter:

```
\begin{document}
<<ch7, child='ch07.Rnw'>>=
@
...
\end{document}
```

I'd like to parametrize the `\setcounter{}` calls with a chunk.  Here is what I tried, before the `\begin{document}` but it doesn't work, probably because I don't quite know how to mix R and Latex output in a chunk:

```
<<set-counters, results='asis', tidy=FALSE, echo=FALSE>>=
.pages <- c(1, 19, 51, 101, 145, 201, 237)
.chapter <- 7
\setcounter{chapter}{.chapter-1}       % one less than chapter number
\setcounter{page}{.pages[.chapter]-1}  % one less than book page number
@
```

I am getting the following error:

```
> knit2pdf("chapter.Rnw", quiet=TRUE)
Quitting from lines 124-128 (chapter.Rnw) 
Error in parse(text = x, srcfile = src) : <text>:3:1: unexpected input
2: .chapter <- 7
3: \
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thou have forgotten about a call to the `cat` function:

```
cat("\\setcounter{chapter}{", .chapter-1, "}", sep="")
cat("\\setcounter{page}{", .pages[.chapter]-1, "}", sep="")
```

You may call these in a loop, together with `cat("\\include{", filename[.chapter], "}", sep="")`. This is how I typeset my [R book](http://rksiazka.rexamine.com) (each chapter was compiled manually, and then the whole manuscript was generated via aggregation of the resulting `.tex` files).

Comment: Great! Thou hast shown me the light of `cat`, which makes total sense.

Comment: @user101089, BTW, If one of the answers (on any of your question) fixes your issue, you should accept it (click the check mark next to the appropriate answer). That does two things. It lets everyone know your issue has been resolved, and it gives the person that helps you credit for the assist. See [here for a full explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235). Cheers!